# Trouble integrating sample totp policy with sample custom sendgrid display controls in custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have integrated both sample policies individually but when i add totp sample extending the custom email sample the qr scan code page does not appear on singup. It is working fine on signin.

here is the totp extension framework policy code

```
     <ClaimsSchema>
      <!--TOTP claims-->
      <ClaimType Id="emails">
        <DisplayName>Email Addresses</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Email addresses of the user.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Your email addresses.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="ReadOnlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>ReadOnlyEmail</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Add help text here</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="totpIdentifier">
        <DisplayName>UserId, Phone number or Email which can present the user's identity</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>UserId, Phone number or Email which can be used to create QR code identity.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="numberOfAvailableDevices">
        <DisplayName>Number of available devices:</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="QrCodeScanInstruction">
        <DisplayName>Once you've downloaded the Authenticator app, you can use any of the methods below to continue with enrollment.</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="QrCodeVerifyInstruction">
        <DisplayName>Enter the verification code from your authenticator app​.</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="qrCodeContent">
        <DisplayName>QR Code Text</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>QR code text</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="secretKey">
        <DisplayName>If you cant't scan the image, enter the Secret Key:</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>QR code secret</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="otpCode">
        <DisplayName>Enter your code</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Enter the 6-digit verification code generated by the the Authenticator app in the box</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[0-9]{6}$" HelpText="Enter the 6-digit verification code generated by the the Authenticator app in the box" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="uriLabel">
        <DisplayName>Uri Label</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="issuer">
        <DisplayName>Issuer</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="UserId">
        <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText />
        <UserHelpText>Your username.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$" HelpText="The username you have provided is not valid. It must begin with an alphabetical character or number, and can only contain alphanumeric characters and the following symbols: _ -" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>

      <!--End of TOTP Claims-->
    </ClaimsSchema>
    //claims are defined
   <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetEmailFromReadOnlyEmail" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    //transformations are defined
```

unfortunately the file is too big and i cannot provide complete file code due to stackoverflow character limit if you need something else let me know.
i tried adding the applicaiton insights to check for exceptions and here is the exception that i get:
Exception Message:A Claim of ClaimType with id "totpIdentifier" was not found, which is required by the ClaimsTransformationImpl of Type "Microsoft.Cpim.Data.Transformations.FormatStringMultipleClaimsTransformation" for TransformationMethod "FormatStringMultipleClaims" referenced by the ClaimsTransformation with id "CreateUriLabel" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "****.onmicrosoft.com"., Exception Type:PolicyException, CorrelationID:****

Any help would be grate Thanks!

Comment: actually no i have setup application insights after that the exception is being thrown which i mentioned in the question. don't know how to handle this exception as i have totpIdentifier and transformation in my code still getting this error

Comment: no it does not i asked the same quesiton we have setup application insights and found the exception still not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Display page content azure custom policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357934/cannot-display-page-content-azure-custom-policies)

Comment: no it does not!